# Django collect the static files fails

Tags: python, django

While I run `python manage.py collectstatic`

It says `You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.`

This is my settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
]
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `STATIC_ROOT` as a parameter to your settings.py.

*Here is how it works with those static files:*

In `STATICFILES_DIRS` you tell django where to go and look for static files. This not primarily to serve them, but to collect them! The point is that on a productive server, django is not supposed to server static files, this task should be handled by the web server. [Check the docs for details.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/deployment/) The idea is that you run the command [`python manage.py collectstatic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/#deployment) and django will go through all the paths in `STATICFILES_DIRS`, collect the static files and put them... - exactly! - into the `STATIC_ROOT` folder.

At this point **2 things should become clear**:

**1.** You need to provide `STATIC_ROOT` in your settings.py.

**2.** The path provided in `STATIC_ROOT` cannot be part of `STATICFILES_DIRS`, as this would mean django would need to put the folder into itself.

Again, this is in the case of a productive server. During development django can handle static files without help of a web server, [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development) is more from the docs on that. Nevertheless, the `STATIC_ROOT` parameter is always required.

Hope that helped to clarify things. Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 2):

`STATICFILES_DIRS` tells django where to look for files to collect when using the `collectstatic` command

`STATIC_ROOT="../my_real_static_folder"` will tell django to put the static files it collects there and the `static_url` will get files from there.

... however be warned serving static files through django only works if debug is True (in settings.py) and is strongly discourages in production environments

Answer (score 1):

Set `STATIC_ROOT = 'path to ur static root directory'` in settings.py. 
Note that when you run `collectstatic` all files from ur static dirs are collected to the static root directory provided in static root path above. U can find more info about this in documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/)